# How do I check the boolean return value of my function

Tags: python

This is a basic version of my code.

It says there's a problem with my "h = abc(shotX,shotY)" statement. Is that the correct way to check the return value of my function? It keeps saying "name shotX not defined".

```
def abc(shotX,shotY)
    x = abs(300 - shotX)
    y = abs(300 - shotY)
if x < 150 and y < 150:
    return True
else:
    return False

def main():
    h = abc(shotX,shotY)
    if h:
        print("h is", h)
    else:
        print("no")
```

Comment: missing ':' at the end of function definition in the `abc` function

Comment: You haven't defined the variables shotX or shotY or initialized them in main().

Answer (score 0):

That's because it's not defined, try this. To use a variable you must first initialize it to value, which can be done like `var = "foo"`

```
def abc(shotX,shotY):
    x = abs(300 - shotX)
    y = abs(300 - shotY)
    if x < 150 and y < 150:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def main():
    shotX = 0
    shotY = 0
    h = abc(shotX,shotY)
    if h:
        print("h is", h)
    else:
        print("no")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have committed some serious mistakes here. As for the function main, you have undeclared variables shotX, shotY (because of which you are specifically getting the error).
It should be as:-

```
def main():
    shotX = #something
    shotY = #something
    h = abc(shotX,shotY)
    if h:
        print("h is", h)
    else:
        print("no")
```

Also you have indentation problems and missing semicolons at function abc

```
def abc(shotX,shotY):
    x = abs(300 - shotX)
    y = abs(300 - shotY)
    if x < 150 and y < 150:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Now your code should work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. add a "**:**" at the end of your "def abc():"
2. Make sure you add "shotX" and "shotY" as parameters in your "def main()"
3. if you want you can set shotY and shotY as global variables above your functions as well if you plan to use them again. (NOTE: if you do follow this step and you happen to change their value inside your function then that is the value that will be used. if NO value is set inside your function then python will use the "Global Variable")

**Answer 1:**

```
def abc(): <--

x = abs(300 - shotX)
y = abs(300 - shotY)
if x < 150 and y < 150:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

**Answer 2:**

```
def main(shotX,shotY):

h = abc(shotX,shotY)
if h:
    print("h is", h)
else:
    print("no")
```

**Answer 3:**

```
shotX = # any int
shotY = # any int

def abc(shotX,shotY):

    x = abs(300 - shotX)
    y = abs(300 - shotY)
```